# Why is it throwing this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java, class

The code is throwing the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Its definitely this part of the code (and where it leads to):

```
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 30; idx++) {
            simulation.moveToNextStation();
        }
```

Looks like there's a loop that is not being exited out of.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3511)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3480)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:454)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
    at com.easy.remember.Station.addCars(Station.java:37)
    at com.easy.remember.Simulation.moveToNextStation(Simulation.java:80)
    at com.easy.remember.Simulation.main(Simulation.java:103)
```

Car class:

```
package com.easy.remember;

import java.util.*;

public class Car
{
   private Station destination;
   private Station currentStation;
   private Station startStation;
   private int currentPassengers;
   private static final int CAPACITY = 3;
   private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers;
   private int revenueCollected;

   public Car(Station startStation, Station currentStation, Station destination)
   {
       this.startStation = startStation;
       this.currentStation = currentStation;
       this.destination = destination;
       currentPassengers = 0;
       revenueCollected = 0;
       passengers = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public boolean pickPassenger(Passenger passenger)
   {
       if(!spaceAvailable())
           return false;
       passengers.add(passenger);
       currentPassengers++;
       return true;
   }

   public void dropPassenger()
   {
       if(passengers.isEmpty())
       return;

       for(int idx = 0; idx < passengers.size(); idx++)
       {
           Passenger currentPassenger = passengers.get(idx);
           if(currentPassenger.checkDestinationReached(currentStation))
           {
               revenueCollected += currentPassenger.payFare();
               passengers.remove(idx--);
               currentPassengers--;
           }
       }
   }

   public boolean spaceAvailable()
   {
       return currentPassengers < CAPACITY;
   }

   public int getRevenueCollected()
   {
       return revenueCollected;
   }

   public int getMilesDriven()
   {
       return destination.getStationNumber() - startStation.getStationNumber();
   }

   public void moveToNextStation(Station next)
   {
       currentStation = next;
   }

   public boolean isDestinationReached()
   {
       return currentStation.equals(destination);
   }

   public String toString()
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("Start Station: " + startStation +
               "; current Station: " + currentStation + ";Current Number " +
               " of Passengers: " + currentPassengers + ";Revenue" + " Collected: " + revenueCollected);
       return sb.toString();
   }

   public int getCurrentPassengers()
   {
       return currentPassengers;
   }

   public Station getDestination()
   {
       return destination;
   }

   public ArrayList<Passenger>getPassengers()
   {
       return passengers;
   }

}
```

Passenger class:

```
package com.easy.remember;

public class Passenger
{
    private Station destination;
    private Station startStation;

    public Passenger(Station startStation, Station destination)
    {
        this.startStation = startStation;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Station getDestination()
    {
        return destination;
    }

    public Station getStartStation()
    {
        return startStation;
    }

    public boolean checkDestinationReached(Station currentStation)
    {
        return destination.equals(currentStation);
    }

    public int payFare()
    {
        return destination.getStationNumber() - startStation.getStationNumber();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Start Station: " + startStation + " Destination: " + destination;
    }
}
```

Station class:

```
package com.easy.remember;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;


public class Station
{
    private ArrayList<Car> cars;
    private ArrayList<Passenger>passengers;
    private int totalRevenueGenerated;
    private int totalMiles;
    private final int stationNumber;

    public Station(int stationNumber)
    {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
        passengers = new ArrayList<>();
        totalRevenueGenerated = 0;
        totalMiles = 0;
        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;
    }

    public int getStationNumber()
    {
        return stationNumber;
    }

    public void addCar(Car car)
    {
        cars.add(car);
    }

    public void addCars(ArrayList<Car>cars)
    {
        for(Car current: cars)
            this.cars.add(current);
    }

    public void addPassenger(Passenger pass)
    {
        passengers.add(pass);
    }

    public int getTotalMiles()
    {
        return totalMiles;
    }

    public int getTotalRevenueGenerated()
    {
        return totalRevenueGenerated;
    }

    public void collectRevenue()
    {
        for(int idx = 0; idx < cars.size(); idx++)
        {
            Car current = cars.get(idx);
            if(current.isDestinationReached())
            {
                totalRevenueGenerated += current.getRevenueCollected();
                totalMiles += current.getMilesDriven();
                cars.remove(idx--);
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadUnloadPassengers()
    {
        for(int idx = 0; idx < cars.size(); idx++)
        {
            cars.get(idx).dropPassenger();
        }

        if(passengers.isEmpty())
        return;

        for(int idx = 0; idx < cars.size(); idx++)
        {
            Car current = cars.get(idx);
            if(!current.spaceAvailable())
            continue;
            int requiredPassengers = 3 - current.getCurrentPassengers();
            for(int jdx = 0; jdx < requiredPassengers; jdx++)
            {
                for(int kdx = 0; kdx < passengers.size(); kdx++)
                {
                    if(passengers.get(kdx)
                    .getDestination()
                    .getStationNumber() <=
                    current.getDestination()
                    .getStationNumber())
                    {
                        current.pickPassenger(
                        passengers.get(kdx));
                        passengers.remove(kdx--);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!current.spaceAvailable() || passengers.isEmpty())
                break;
                }
            if(passengers.isEmpty())
            break;
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Car> moveCars()
        {
            return cars;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            Station rhs = (Station)obj;
            return getStationNumber() == rhs.getStationNumber();
        }

        public void printAllCars()
        {
            for(Car current : cars)
                System.out.println(current);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "" + stationNumber;
        }
    }
```

Simulation class:

```
package com.easy.remember;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Simulation {
    private ArrayList<Station> stations;
    private int currentStationIndex;
    private int miles;
    private int revenue;

    public Simulation() {
        stations = new ArrayList<>();
        currentStationIndex = 0;
    }

    public void addStation(Station station) {
        stations.add(station);
    }

    public Station getStation(int index) {
        return stations.get(index);
    }

    public void generateCars(Station station) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int numCars = randomGenerator.nextInt(30);
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= numCars; idx++) {
            Car car = null;
            int destination = randomGenerator.nextInt(30 - station.getStationNumber() + 1);
            car = new Car(station, station, new Station(destination + station.getStationNumber() - 1));
            station.addCar(car);
        }
    }

    public int getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public int getRevenue() {
        return revenue;
    }

    public void generatePassengers(Station station) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int numPassengers = randomGenerator.nextInt(60);
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= numPassengers; idx++) {
            Passenger passenger = null;
            int destination = randomGenerator.nextInt(30 - station.getStationNumber() + 1);
            passenger = new Passenger(station, new Station(destination + station.getStationNumber() - 1));
            station.addPassenger(passenger);
        }
    }

    public void moveToNextStation() {
        Station currentStation = stations.get(currentStationIndex++);
        Station nextStation = null;

        try {
            nextStation = stations.get(currentStationIndex);

        } catch (Exception except) {
            nextStation = null;
        }

        if(currentStationIndex == 0) {
            currentStation.collectRevenue();
        } else {
            currentStation.loadUnloadPassengers();
            currentStation.collectRevenue();
        }

        revenue += currentStation.getTotalRevenueGenerated();
        miles += currentStation.getTotalMiles();

        if (nextStation != null) {
            ArrayList<Car> carsToMove = currentStation.moveCars();
            for (Car current : carsToMove) {
                current.moveToNextStation(nextStation);
                nextStation.addCars(carsToMove);
            }/**    */
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simulation simulation = null;
        double totalRevenuePerMile = 0;

        //for (int jdx = 1; jdx <= 3; jdx++)
        //{
        simulation = new Simulation();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 30; idx++) {
            simulation.addStation(new Station(idx));
        }

        for (int idx = 0; idx < 30; idx++) {
            simulation.generateCars(simulation.getStation(idx));
            simulation.generatePassengers(simulation.getStation(idx));
        }

        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 30; idx++) {
            simulation.moveToNextStation();
        }

        double revenuePerMile = ((double) simulation.getRevenue()) / simulation.getMiles();

        totalRevenuePerMile += revenuePerMile;
         //}

        System.out.println("Average revenue per " + " mile in 1000 simulations is: \n" + totalRevenuePerMile);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that the application does not have enough memory to continue. Please [edit] the post and include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop seems problematic (in `Simulation.moveToNextStation`):

```
ArrayList<Car> carsToMove = currentStation.moveCars();
for (Car current : carsToMove) {
    current.moveToNextStation(nextStation);
    nextStation.addCars(carsToMove);
}
```

For the current station, you loop on each car but then add *all* the cars to the next station *for each car*.  So if you had 30 cars initially then the next station would have 900 cars and then the next station would have 810000 cars...etc.  That may lead to an out-of-memory quickly.

At first glance you have 30 cars and 30 stations.  If it could have finished you'd have 30^30 cars at the final station: that's roughly 2.05x10^44 cars or over a duodecillion of cars.

Comment: Phenomenal! That solved it. Program works now. Thx!